# Zend Framework multi-step form generator

Tags: php, mysql, forms, zend-framework

I am working on a form generator for a multistep form submission.

I have a steps table, each step has multiple groups, each group has multiple questions and finally each question has its own options, all of which are related to a program.

I am building with zend framework.

I created an sql statement in order to have the full result set as follows

```
$resultSet = $db->fetchAll($db->select()->from(array('rs' => 'registration_steps'))
   ->joinInner(array('rg' => 'registration_groups'), 'rs.id = rg.registration_step_id')
   ->joinInner(array('rq' => 'registration_questions'), 'rq.registration_group = rg.id')
   ->joinInner(array('qo' => 'registration_question_options'), 'rq.id = qo.question_id', array('option_text'))
   ->where('rs.program_id =?', $program_id));
```

The problem is obvious, i am getting duplicate results because am doing inner joins with the options.

While this might work if i parse the whole thing on the client side, i want to find a more optimized or a better way of doing it.